# Local Parse Server Push Configuration

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I have a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu and Parse Server.  Parse Server works good, but im trying to configure it to enable push notification.  From WIKI parse, i know that i need to edit a config file with JS extension and write:

```
var server = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: '...',
  cloud: '...',
  appId: '...',
  masterKey: '...',
  push: {
    android: {
      senderId: '...',
      apiKey: '...'
    },
    ios: {
      pfx: '/file/path/to/XXX.p12',
      bundleId: '',
      production: false
    }
  }
});
```

But the problem is that i do not know where is that `index.js` file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

SOLVED:
thanks, i solved using the parse server example from github editing the index.js file and editing the main.js file in cloud directory.
In main.js now there is a function to send push notification, and i call that function from Swift. Now push notification works ! :)

Comment: Please have a look at parse server example repository at https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example. It might help.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but the source code and the path tree of the repository example  is different from a stand alone parse version without Express Framework.

Comment: news, probably i find the solution : start parse-server with push parameter and all configuration value in json format, tonight i will try and i will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally index.js file is available in parse-server-example directory.

Add or Edit below code in index.js file

```
var server = new ParseServer({   
databaseURI: '...',
cloud: '...',
appId: '...',
masterKey: '...',
  push: {
    android: {
      senderId: '...',
      apiKey: '...'
      },
    ios: {
      pfx: '/file/path/to/XXX.p12',
      bundleId: '',
      production: false //true for production
    }
  }
});
```

After that you can make below curl request to get users data, this will return all the users with information:-

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: YOUR_MASTER_KEY" \  http://localhost:1337/parse/installations
```

To send push notification to users you need to make below curl request:-

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: YOUR_MASTER_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
      "where": {
      "deviceType": {
        "$in": [
          "ios",
          "android"
        ]
      },
      "deviceToken":"xxxxx"
    },
      "data": {
        "title": "Notification",
        "alert": "Great Notification Message"
      }
    }'\   http://localhost:1337/parse/push
```